# How to use If-Statement without add curly brackets?

Tags: java

java newbie here.I was practicing array problem on codingbat.

You can find this question on here [codingbat](http://codingbat.com/prob/p136648).

Here is the problem:"Given an array of ints, return true if it contains no 1's or it contains no 4's."

I solved this problem by using `boolean` and `if-statement`.

My code:

```
public boolean no14(int[] nums) {
    boolean find1s=false;
    boolean find4s=false;

    for(int i=0;i<nums.length;i++){
        if(nums[i]==1)
            find1s=true;
        if(nums[i]==4)
            find4s=true;
    }

    if(ones && fours)
        return false;
    else
        return true;
}
```

The question is when I tried to add `{}` in my first if-statement, it always need me to return something. So I delete the `{}`, and it was right.

So can I use if-statement without curly bracket? and when can I do it?

Comment: I'd advise you not to do this.  Add the braces all the time, even for bodies with a single line.  It's not much more work; it'll help develop good habits and avoid mistakes.  It's a false economy.

Comment: Yes, you can use if without curly brackets just if you want to execute one statement after if.
But in case of execute multiple statement you can't

Comment: By saying "when I tried to add {} in my first if-statement, it always need me to return something" its about return statment or something else?

Comment: @JohnG what is your basis for saying this?  Looking at the examples at the link, their description is correct, and yours is wrong.

Comment: You say that when you tried to add `{}` you got some kind of error.  Could you show us how you did that, so that maybe we could help tell what you did wrong?  `if(nums[i]==1) { find1s=true; }` should never give you an error, so apparently you did something different.

Comment: @ajb … you are correct… I was not looking at it from the proper truth table perspective. If there is a 1 AND 4, both return false. Otherwise one will be true and will return true with an “OR” condition. Thank you for pointing out my invalid comment. I will remove it. Thank you for your constructive SO comment, I will be more careful in the future. Can someone pass the gravy… this shoe is really tough.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Java, braces (`{}`) are only *required* around conditional blocks that have multiple statements. Otherwise, only the first is executed conditionally. In essence:

```
if (something)
    doThing1();
    doThing2();
doThing3();
```

is really

```
if (something){
    doThing1();
}
doThing2();
doThing3();
```

While it is true that they aren't *required* in these single statement conditional sections, it's considered extremely good practice to use them in any case: using braces where you didn't need them is harmless and future proof, but not using them where you need them has caused genuinely disastrous bugs in the past.